# Silverlight business application deployment issues

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am having problems with my Silverlight 5 business application deployment. Once deployed to the server the Silverlight application does not connect to the RIA service. It runs fine through VS and the service runs fine locally. If I put in the server path for the service I get the following error

`Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.`

Any assistance is appreciated

Comment: did you check whether correct dll is deployed

Answer (score 0):

You should check these items:

- If you use .NET Framework 4 (or 4.5), make sure this version has been installed on the server
- Check .NET Framework version of your application pool. You must set it to `.NET v4.0`
- Finally, you should check .NET Framework version of your project in visual studio, you should set it to 4 or 4.5